# When I set component's state with concat I receive error: Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

Tags: reactjs, concatenation, state, unique-key, react-props

My React component renders a twitter stream.  The original version works correctly, but the componentDidMount method mutates the component's state:

**(Original) components/Stream.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Stream extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { streamItems: [] }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/tweets')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(tweets => this.setState({ streamItems: tweets }));
  }

 render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h1>Tweets</h1>
          <div className='stream-items'>
            {this.state.streamItems.map(tweet =>
              <div key={tweet.id}>{tweet.text}</div>
            )}
        </div>
        <Button
          className='btn-remove'
          onClick={() => this.props.removeStream(this.props.stream.id)}
        >
        Remove Stream
        </ Button>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default Stream;
```

To prevent the component's state being mutated I setState using concat instead:

**components/Stream.js (updated method only)**

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/tweets')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(tweets => this.setState({
        streamItems: this.state.streamItems.concat([tweets])
      }))
  }
```

I now receive the error:

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique
>   "key" prop.

This is confusing as I have set the key in the component's render method.

Comment: please share the structure of `tweets `?

Comment: The raw json is long so here's a link to the example: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline.html

Answer (score 0):

> **Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.**

```
    streamItems: this.state.streamItems.concat([tweets])
```

Its look like `tweets` is not having `id`.Its coming `undefined`.So,React throwing an error. Or you need to spread it

```
streamItems: this.state.streamItems.concat([...tweets])
```

**Note:**

You don't need to use `concat`.You can do like this.

```
streamItems:[...this.state.streamItems,tweets]
```